# How to deduce open mapping theorem from closed graph theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, alternative-proof

These two theorems are equivalent but I can not figure out how to deduce the open mapping from the closed graph. Can anyone give a hint or some reference?

Comment: http://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/closed-graph-theorem-implies-open-mapping-theorem/  (I haven't checked this...).

Comment: You might be interested in [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/137673/5363)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The proof linked to by David is the standard one, but the write-up strikes me as  somewhat clumsy.

Here's my take on this argument:

Suppose $T: X \to Y$ is continuous and onto.

1. The map $\pi: X \to \bar{X} = X/ \operatorname{Ker}{T}$ is open, onto and continuous. The map $T$ factors over $\pi$ via a continuous linear bijection $\bar{T}: \bar{X} \to Y$ by definition of the quotient topology.
2. By continuity of $\bar{T}$ the graph of $\bar{T}$ is closed. Switching coordinates $(\bar{x},y) \mapsto (y,\bar{x})$ is a homeomorphism $\bar{X} \times Y \to Y \times \bar{X}$ and it maps the graph of $\bar{T}$ to the graph of $\bar{T}^{-1}$, so the graph of the linear map $\bar{T}^{-1}$ is closed, too. By the closed graph theorem $\bar{T}^{-1}$ is continuous.
3. For all open $U \subset X$ the set $T(U) \subset Y$ is open because it is the pre-image of the open set $\pi(U)$ under the continuous map $\bar{T}^{-1}$, hence $T$ is open.

**Note:** Step 2. is a proof of the inverse mapping theorem from the closed graph theorem.

Comment: how do you know the map $\pi$ is open in step 1?

Comment: I think its because we give the quotient topology to $\bar{X}$. The quotient topology says that a set $\bar{U}$ in $\bar{X}$ is open iff the pre-image under the quotient map is open, i.e. $\pi^{-1}(\bar{U})$ is open. And thus almost by definition you get that $\pi$ is open.

Comment: In general, the quotient map may not always be open, but it is true when we are quotienting by a closed subspace. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4330993/732515 for the proof.