# seminorm with $\sigma$-additivity is continuous

Tags: banach-spaces, functional-equations

$E$ is a $Banach$ space, $p$ is a seminorm on $E$ if $p$ satisfies $\sigma$-additivity, i.e. if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n $ converges in $E$, then $$p(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty p(x_n) \le \infty$$
Show $p$ is continuous.

I know it's equivalent to that $\exists M \ge 0$, such that $p(x) \le M\|x\|.$

I made the following attempt:

$\forall x \in E\quad \forall (x_n), x_n \to x$. Let $y_1=x_1, y_n=x_n -x_{n-1},n \ge 2$.
Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n \to x,$

then $p(x)=p(\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty p(y_n).$

But I couldn't find the relationship between $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(y_n)$ and $\|x\|.$

Comment: The question is Zabreiko's lemma

Comment: https://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/06/25/zabreikos-lemma-and-four-fundamental-theorems-of-functional-analysis/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Direct approach to the Closed Graph Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137673/direct-approach-to-the-closed-graph-theorem)